# Jupyter keeps crashing when using BERTopic's fit_transform()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

`topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs)`

Whenever I run fit_transform like in the line above, my Jupyter notebook keeps dying, and I don't know why. I am using Python 3.9.15 on a macOS 13.4.1 with the Apple M1 chip. Here are the versions of my Jupyter core packages:

[Jupyter package versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDMLc.png)

I've been able to fit machine learning models before with Sci-Kit learn, so I'm not sure why BERTopic is causing these issues.

Comment: When creating topic_model, can you set verbose=True, and share the logs leading to the break `topic_model = BERTopic(verbose=True)`? Can you also monitor memory usage to see if your a running out?

Comment: The cell just doesn't run, so I cannot see the logs. Also, how do you monitor memory usage on Jupyter?

Answer (score 0):

BERTopic is indeed resource-intensive, and it's very likely that you've exhausted your available resources. Based on your comment, here's a great link to help you [monitor your memory usage](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/howto/admin/nbresuse.html) on Jupyter. If that's not the case, restarting your kernel might help. Otherwise, it's possible that package incompatibility is causing the problem. It'd be great if you could provide us with more specific details.

Comment: It might be because of the version of NumPy I have. I got a message stating this: "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Answer (score 0):

I found a [report](https://bugs.python.org/issue39397) of the error you reported (thanks for that!) and it was related to the instantiation of the env variable `LANG` to "en-US" which then set the encoding to the same value rather than UTF-8. Can you take a look at your .bash or .zshrc file?

Comment: The linked report does not seem particularly related to this question.